# "The whole nine yards"

Tags: etymology, phrases, popular-refrains

What is the origin of the phrase "the whole nine yards"? Is it a reference to some game of sports I am not familiar with (as a continental European)?

Comment: Since you posted this question, there have been some interesting [developments](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?p=13416192) in tracking down the origin of this phrase.

Comment: [Ken Greenwald, at Wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=6476&p=87627&hilit=nine+yaRDS#p87627), gives his usual thorough and balanced overview. There's no definite answer.

Comment: @Edwin It might be too late to be interesting now, and when I just tried to follow Ken Greenwald, at Wordwizard, your link took me to a site-name sale at some web-service provider…

Comment: It looks like Phil White eventually gave up funding the site. Ken was a master at researching etymologies. I hope his legacy persists somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot of exciting possibilities [listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_whole_nine_yards), but it sounds as if nobody knows for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Like Gaurav said, nobody knows for sure. [Here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-whole-nine-yards.html) is a well sourced and interesting article on the topic. [Here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-whole-whole-nine-yards-enchilida.html) the author writes about the impassioned responses that the article evoked from his readers.

Comment: +1 for an amusing read, though after looking closer I noticed that it is actually referenced in the Wikipedia article, so I'm inclined to mark Gaurav's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

New research suggests the nine was just an arbitrary number.

A recent discovery of a *whole six yards* of this "Holy Grail among word sleuths" suggests the modern phrase is an example of "phrase inflation", similar to *cloud nine*'s inflation from the earlier *cloud seven* and *cloud eight*.

Yale law librarian Fred R. Shapiro wrote in the *Yale Alumni Magazine* (Jan/Feb 2013):

> [Bonnie] Taylor-Blake’s next discovery took the research in a completely unexpected direction. Searching  Google News Archive, she found, in the sports section of the *Spartanburg* (South Carolina) *Herald-Journal* of May 7, 1921, an article about a baseball game between the Spartanburg Spartans and the Greenville Spinners. With it was a more detailed, at-bat-by-at-bat description of the same game. The headline of the detailed account? “The Whole Six Yards of It.”
>
> That headline appears to use “the whole six yards” in exactly the same sense as we now use “the whole nine yards.” I found confirmation via the database Chronicling America. An article in the *Mount Vernon* (Kentucky) *Signal* of May 17, 1912, states: “But there is one thing sure, we dems would never have known that there was such crookedness in the Rebublican [sic] party if Ted and Taft had not got crossed at each other. Just wait boys until the fix gets to a fever heat and they will tell the whole six yards.” And again, in the June 28, 1912, issue: “As we have been gone for a few days and failed to get all the news for this issue we will give you the whole six yards in our next.”

Comment: Very interesting. Rather than resolve anything, though, this discovery seems to open up more lines of inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

There is a high likelihood that it refers to nine yards of fabric.  Nine yards of fabric was a common standard length for retail sale at least in the mid-to-late 1800s and into the early 1900s.  http://esnpc.blogspot.com/2015/02/nine-yards-to-dollar-history-and.html

Answer (score -3):

It's a reference to the length of a typical machine gun ammo belt in the First World War, I do believe.

Comment: I do believe you mean the Second World War, and it referred to the length of the ammo belts used by waist gunners in B-17s.